# how to filter and sort fields in django-filter that are not in Django model?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to filter values in 2 fields that I am creating in my serializer and I am wondering how to add last_run and lat_status to filtering and orting fieldset but when I am adding them I get `Cannot resolve keyword 'last_status' into field.` error.

Is there any option to annotate these 2 fields in my ListAPIView so  I can sort and filter by them

sample API data

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "user": 1,
  "project": 3,
  "last_run": "17-08-2023 16:45",
  "last_status": "SUCCESS",
  "name": "test spider",
  "creation_date": "10-08-2023 12:36",
},
```

models.py

```
class Spider(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="", unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default='')
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='project_spider')
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

serializers.py

```
class SpiderListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all())
    last_run = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    last_status = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Spider
        fields = "__all__"

    def get_last_run(self, instance):
        return get_last_spider_status(instance.id)[0]

    def get_last_status(self, instance):
        return get_last_spider_status(instance.id)[1]
```

filters.py

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from .models import Spider

class SpiderFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    name = filters.CharFilter(field_name='name', lookup_expr='icontains')
    user = filters.NumberFilter(field_name='user__id', lookup_expr='icontains')
    project = filters.NumberFilter(field_name='project__id', lookup_expr='icontains')
    creation_date = filters.DateFilter(
        field_name='creation_date',
        input_formats=['%d-%m-%Y'],
        lookup_expr='icontains'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Spider
        fields = []
```

views.py

```
class SpiderListView(ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = SpiderListSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter]
    filterset_class = SpiderFilter
    ordering_fields = ['name', 'user', 'project', 'creation_date'] # how to add 'last_run' and 'last_status' fields to this list
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to add **.annotate()** for new non-model fields to your **queryset** attribute in ListCreateAPIView and filter by them because I doubt one can filter based on "serializer-only" fields. I cannot see whats your *get_spider_status* implementation but I guess it could be replaced by query expression.

you can read about filtering on annotations in detail here - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).